# How I can send a request to another server from OpenResty?

Tags: http, nginx, openresty

I have OpenResty, how do I send a request to another server and parse the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use one of libraries meant for that, eg. [lua-resty-http](https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http) or [lua-resty-requests](https://github.com/tokers/lua-resty-requests). Both can be installed by OPM or LuaRocks.

Another, more advanced / hacky solutions are (ab)using [ngx.location.capture](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) with appropriate upstream definition or rolling your own support by direct use of [ngx.socket.tcp](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsockettcp) (that's what all libraries are using underneath).

You can find more useful resources on this list: https://github.com/bungle/awesome-resty